# Regular expression to extract UPPERCASE words between given start and end strings

Tags: regex-group, regexp-replace

I am trying to replace "MR JOE JOE" to (NAME) in the given sentence starting with "Transfer from" and ending with "CREDIT TO ACCOUNT" using the following code in Snowflake:

```
select regexp_replace('Transfer From MR JOE JOE to PayID Phone CREDIT TO ACCOUNT', '(.*Transfer From)|(CREDIT TO ACCOUNT)|\\b([A-Z]{1,})\\b|(\\b(to \\w+\\w+)\\b)',
'\\1 (NAME) \\5 \\2');
```

The output I get is as follows:

*Transfer From (NAME) (NAME) (NAME) (NAME) (NAME) to PayID Phone (NAME) CREDIT TO ACCOUNT*

**Desired Output:**

*Transfer From (NAME) to PayID Phone CREDIT TO ACCOUNT*

I couldn't make the right pattern for matching groups and replacements. How do I do it? Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please edit your post to show what RDBMS you are using.

Comment: I am trying to do this in Snowflake. Post edited now. Thanks @Gary_W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it in Oracle given the information you posted.  Perhaps this would apply to your RDBMS?

```
select 
  regexp_replace('Transfer From MR JOE JOE to PayID Phone CREDIT TO ACCOUNT', 
  '(.*Transfer From )(.*)( to .* CREDIT TO ACCOUNT)',
  '\1(NAME)\3') replace
from dual;


REPLACE                                              
-----------------------------------------------------
Transfer From (NAME) to PayID Phone CREDIT TO ACCOUNT
```

Comment: Thanks again @Gary_W. The second group should only match uppercase words separated by space. Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

```
select regexp_replace('Transfer From MR JOE JOE to PayID Phone CREDIT TO ACCOUNT', '(.*Transfer From )[A-Z\\s]+( to .* CREDIT TO ACCOUNT)',
'\\1(NAME)\\2');
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**